# MYSQL Multi group by and max

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max

Here is a table called posts_votes

```
id|discussion_id|post_id|user_id|vote_sign|
__________________________________________
1 |      1      |   1   |   1   |     1   |
2 |      1      |   1   |   2   |    -1   |
3 |      1      |   2   |   3   |     1   |
4 |      1      |   2   |   4   |     1   |
5 |      2      |   3   |   1   |    -1   |
6 |      2      |   4   |   2   |     1   |
```

I want to create a view with theses results:

```
discussion_id|post_id|score
      1      |   2   | 2
      2      |   4   | 1
```

With :

- post_id is the post with best score
- score is SUM(vote_sign)

I'm torturing my mind with group by and having max but I find no way to do it.. =(

If somebody has an idea...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sub-queries to first calculate the scores and select max score for each discussion_id. Then `join` the result sets to get the post with max score for each discussion_id.

```
select t1.*
from (select discussion_id,post_id,sum(vote_sign) as score
      from posts_votes
      group by discussion_id,post_id) t1
join (select discussion_id,max(score) as maxscore 
      from (select discussion_id,post_id,sum(vote_sign) as score
            from posts_votes
            group by discussion_id,post_id) t
      group by discussion_id) t2 
on t1.discussion_id = t2.discussion_id and t1.score = t2.maxscore
```

Comment: Yes.it is necessary @Strawberry..it would have been way easier with other dbms's which support window functions.

Comment: Yay! Thank you ! This works fine, only downside if two items have the same score, but I'll handle it in code !

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(post_id ORDER BY sm DESC), ',', 1)  AS top_post, discussion_id, max(score) as score
from (
    select discussion_id, post_id, sum(vote_sign) as score
    from posts_votes
    group by post_id, discussion_id
) c
group by discussion_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select discussion_id, max(post_id), sum(vote_sign)
from posts_votes
group by discussion_id;
```

Comment: this just happens to give the correct solution with the sample data, but max(post_id) won't always give back the correct post.

Answer (score 0):

Here the query corresponding to your question

```
select
  discussion_id, 
  max(post_id) as max_post_id,
  sum(vote_sign) as score
from
  posts_votes 
group by
  discussion_id;
```